# How to get a value fro a hash in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my view:

```
<%= post.book %>
```

gives me:

```
#<Book:0x007fbb885e94a8>
```

I added `inspect`:

```
<%= post.book.inspect %>
```

and I get:

```
#<Book id: 2, author: "Bob", created_at: "2016-05-07 05:19:04", updated_at: "2016-05-07 05:19:04">
```

If I do `<%= post.book.author %>` I get:

```
undefined method `author' for nil:NilClass
```

What I'm trying to display is just the author "Bob".

If I'm in the post/show view I can make it work with `post.book.author`, but I'm in a different view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see, you should do this:

```
<%= post.try(:book).try(:author) %>
```